# How does Typekit work behind the scenes?

Tags: html, fonts

I'm curious if anyone has an idea about how this stuff works behind the scenes.  I'm interested if there is a way to host your own fonts and also if those would work for all major browsers out there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found [this interesting post](http://blog.typekit.com/2009/07/21/serving-and-protecting-fonts-on-the-web/) on Typekit's blog. This was the kind of answer that I was looking for.

**Edit**: I wrote a [web font server](https://github.com/noll/mjau) which borrows some of the techniques described in the article.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest looking up [WOFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOFF) (Web Open Font Format). There should be various applications (at least one free web app) available for converting regular desktop fonts to WOFF.

The only real obstacle to embedding any font you want are licensing restrictions, and that is what Typekit was created to solve. They provide a means to legally embed web fonts that they've obtained licensing rights for from type foundries—hence the subscription cost.

You can do as Aillyn suggest if you can find free fonts that don't have such licensing restrictions, or you can acquire WOFF fonts that are licensed specifically for web use, and which are also compressed for faster loading. Alternately, you can convert your TrueType/OpenType fonts into WOFF and use any font you want, regardless of legality.

However, the way Typekit embeds fonts is by embedding them directly in the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "bello-pro-1";
    src: url(data:font/woff;base64,...=);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

—where `...` is the WOFF file encoded in Base64. You can also do this yourself once you've acquired a WOFF font.

There's no innate DRM in WOFF, so I'm not sure what has prompted font foundries to suddenly embrace web fonts through WOFF, but from what I've read from a few font designers, it appears that there might be some fundamental misunderstanding of how web pages work and what the "same-origin" policy actually implies.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine they are just embedding fonts like this:

```
@font-face {  
  font-family: " your FontName ";  
  src: url( /location/of/font/FontFileName.eot ); /* IE */  
  src: local(" real FontName "), url( /location/of/font/FontFileName.ttf ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}  

/* THEN use like you would any other font */  
.yourFontName { font-family:" your FontName ", verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;  
}
```

http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680

I tested that and it works for IE8, FF, Chrome and Safari on Windows.

Comment: They're not doing it that way - they're embedding it using Data-URIs, so instead of referencing a font file on a server, the base 64-encoded font is embedded directly into the stylesheet.